# The "Big Five" Bidding Convention in Spades

Tags: bidding, spades

In the game of Spade, the Big 5 conventions (invent by Herm Carney and Roger Denino, as stated in a [video by Joe Andrews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h7Ax2XeugmE&ab_channel=ExpertVillageLeafGroup))  means that if the first partner `bids 5` it signals to the second partner that she can cover a Nil bid.  That is to say, if partners play by this convention, the first bidder only bids `5` when she have certain hand that can cover a partner Nil.

I found the exact rules of when to bid 5 are **vague**.  Of course every couple can decide upon a slightly different convention, however I am interested in the original\popular convention.

I play that the first bidder only bids 5 if have:

1. Ace or King of spade
2. 4 to 6 takes
3. in each of the side-suits, has one of the following options:

   a. Void

   b. Singelton higher than {5}

   c. Doubleton higher than {5,8}

   d. A honor card

My question is, **what exactly a `5 bid` by the first partner represent in the big 5 convention**?

**The vagueness** is mostly in section 3 (cover in side suits).
Another issue I suspect needs to be defined better: if you only have a single spade (Ace or king) is it still acceptable for a bid of 5?

Comment: Is the convention "if someone is able to bid 5, then they can probably cover a nil", or is it "only bid 5 if you can cover a nil"? I suspect it might be the former. Your list sounds more like you can maybe bid 7.

Comment: you right, the former: only bid 5 if you can cover a nil.
I am looking to find exact rules of what it meant to be able to cover Nil.  Since only sections 1+2 is not enough but section 3 can be different than what I suggested.

Comment: "The former" means "the first thing listed" i.e. "If someone is able to bid 5, then they can probably cover a nil". The opposite would be "the latter". Given this, your comment makes no sense.

Comment: That said, having now read your first link it definitely says "only bid 5 if you can cover a nil" and goes through all the guidelines. I don't see the vagueness.

Comment: you are right again, I meant the latter.  The vagueness is in section 3.  In the links they don't specify section 3, just say that you need a cover in sides suits.